# Problem loading a referenced assembly in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

Here's the official problem reported by the compiler.

> Could not load the assembly
>   file:///Q:\Libraries\v2.0\v4.0.30319\Silverlight.dll.
>   This assembly may have been downloaded
>   from the Web.  If an assembly has been
>   downloaded from the Web, it is flagged
>   by Windows as being a Web file, even
>   if it resides on the local computer.
>   This may prevent it from being used in
>   your project. You can change this
>   designation by changing the file
>   properties. Only unblock assemblies
>   that you trust. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179545
>   for more information.

Now I've been a good programmer and did some research to fix this. Here's what I've tried so far.

1. Copy the assembly to a FAT32 drive (flash drive) and then back.
2. Unblock the assembly by hitting the Unblock button in the file properties. (Actually never have been able to get this to work since the button isn't there to begin with)
3. Use the type command in command prompt

Short of disabling this feature, I'm not sure how to fix this problem. Sometimes it happens, sometimes it doesn't. I should mention that the **Q: drive** is a network drive on a separate server. My machine is running Windows 7. The assembly Silverlight.dll is a library created by some of the developers here at work. We just placed it on a shared network drive so everyone could find it easily. Even if I log onto the server and look at the file properties, there isn't a Unblock button like in all the tutorials I've read.

Comment: .NET does not like to load DLLs off of shared drives.  I suggest you don't run it from a shared drive.  Should work like a champ then.

Comment: @Hogan - I've got a dozen or so other projects running in Visual Studio 2010 that all reference these libraries. Why would one project suddenly start having problems when all the other ones work just fine?

Comment: Mystery to me -- is the drive failing?

Comment: At the command prompt, run DIR /R on the file to see if it contains an alternate data stream.  If you see one, ask at serverfault.com how it might have gotten there.  The error message says you did, something like Zone.Identifier

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file onto your local drive (maybe somewhere into the solution/project dir) and then right-click the file in Windows-Explorer.

In the file properties window you will find a warning that this file comes from a remote computer and a button to permit access (In German "Zulassen"). Click it! Now rebuilding your Silverlight application will work.

Screen shot:

[image: File Property Window]

Answer (score 0):

copy it local (I create a Libs folder for all dlls copied locally).

add it as a reference to your project.

in windows explorer right mouse click on the dll and click the UnBlock button on the main tab.

build Silverlight project.

error goes away.